# Locate the largest element in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

When prompted for a number of rows in a matrix, then prompted to enter the elements of those rows, I need to find the largest element in that matrix and return its location (row and column).

For example, if I enter 2 rows as follows:

[1 3 7]
[4 8 1]

the location of the largest element would be (1, 1) meaning row index 1 and column index 1.

I have the following code, which semi works to get the location:

```
def main():
    matrix = []

    numRows = eval(input("Enter the number of rows in the list: "))
    for i in range(numRows):
        rows = input("Enter a row: ")
        items = rows.split()
        list = [eval(x) for x in items]
        matrix.append(list)

    return locateLargest(matrix)

def locateLargest(a):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        indexOfMaxRow = 0
        maxRow = max(a[i])

        for row in range(len(a)):
            if max(a[row]) > maxRow:
                maxRow = max(a[row])
                indexOfMaxRow = row

    for j in range(len(a)):
        indexOfMaxColumn = 0
        maxColumn = max(a[j])

        for column in range(len(a)):
            if max(a[column]) > maxColumn:
                maxColumn = max(a[column])
                indexOfMaxColumn = column

    print("The location of the largest element is at (", indexOfMaxRow, ", ", indexOfMaxColumn, ")")

main()
```

I think my code is wrong under `def locateLargest(a)` since everything works until the results are printed. Can anyone advise what is wrong with it? Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23554004/103081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `locateLargest` function can be much simpler:

```
def locateLargest(matrix):
    largest_num = None 
    row = None
    col = None

    for row_idx, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for col_idx, num in enumerate(row):
            if num > largest_num or largest_num is None:
                largest_num = num
                row = row_idx
                col = col_idx

    return (largest_num, row, col)
```

This function returns the largest number, as well as the column and row index (0 based index).

Example:

```
>>> print(locateLargest([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]))
(9, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tweaked it and used print(), but it works :)

Answer (score 6):

If you can use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), then the indices of maximum value in an array can be easily found:

```
import numpy as np
na = np.array(a)
indices = np.where(na == na.max())
```

Answer (score 2):

That is overly complex:

```
A = [[1, 3, 7],
     [4, 8, 1]]

def max_element(A):
    r, (c, l) = max(map(lambda t: (t[0], max(enumerate(t[1]), key=lambda v: v[1])), enumerate(A)), key=lambda v: v[1][1])
    return (l, r, c)

print max_element(A)
```

Prints

```
(8, 1, 1)
```