# How to find min/max values in array of variable-length arrays with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like the following one:

```
data = [
  [-20],
  [-23],
  [-41],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
]
arr = np.array(data)
```

How can I use numpy to find the minimum/maximum value of each array in `data`?
Neither `np.min` nor `np.max` seem to work, even if I specify a different axis.
The desired result would look like the following:

```
>>> np.findmin(arr)
array([-20, -23, -41, 1, 2, 5])
>>> np.findmax(arr)
array([-20, -23, -41, 3, 3, 9])
```

Also, I'm not entirely clear on why `np.min` and `np.max` aren't working.  Perhaps they would only work the way I want if the given array had well-defined axes where each row had a fixed number of columns?  If anyone can explain this, I would be interested to know.

Comment: That post doesn't answer the question that I'm asking.  The array they're using contains arrays with a constant shape.  I'm asking about arrays with variable shapes.

Comment: that's why its a comment, and not a dupe or an answer.  Its just related reading that may be helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469286/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-maximum-element-in-a-numpy-array provides, in the question, an answer to your question, by using `amax`. Point taken on the variable shape arrays.

Comment: wnnmaw:  Am I not free to point out why the post doesn't answer my question?

Comment: @DavidSanders, you are, but I don't believe it was trying to answer your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but this isn't the sort of thing numpy is good at.  One possible solution is to pad the array with `nan` and use `np.nanmax` like so

```
import numpy as np

def pad_array(arr):
    M = max(len(a) for a in arr)
    return np.array([a + [np.nan] * (M - len(a)) for a in arr])

data = [
  [-20],
  [-23],
  [-41],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
]
arr = pad_array(data)
# array([[-20.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
#        [-23.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
#        [-41.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
#        [  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,  nan],
#        [  2.,   3.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
#        [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.]])

np.nanmin(arr, axis=1) #array([-20., -23., -41.,   1.,   2.,   5.])
np.nanmax(arr, axis=1) #array([-20., -23., -41.,   3.,   3.,   9.])
```

This isn't faster than a regular list comprehension, though. `np.min` and `np.max` *are* working, but numpy doesn't have support for ragged arrays so `np.array(data)` is making a one-dimensional array of objects, and `np.min` is giving you the smallest `object`--the same as you would get if you had used Python's builtin `min` function--the same goes with `np.max`.

Here are the timings comparing creating a padded array and using a plain list comprehension

```
%%timeit
arr = np.array(pad_array(data))
np.nanmin(arr, axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27 µs per loop

%timeit [min(row) for row in data]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 µs per loop
```

This is a bit contrived because I use a list comprehension and a generator expression in `pad_array` so it stands to reason that a single list comprehension is going to be faster, but if you were in a situation where you only needed to create the padded array once, a single list comprehension would still be faster.

```
%timeit np.nanmin(arr, axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 µs per loop
```

**EDIT:**

You could use `np.vectorize` to make a vectorized version of Python's builtin `max` and `min` functions

```
vmax = np.vectorize(max)
vmax(data) #array([-20, -23, -41,   3,   3,   9])
```

It's still not faster than a list comprehension ...

```
%timeit vmax(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.6 µs per loop
```

**EDIT 2**

For the sake of completeness/correctness, it is worth pointing out the the numpy solution will scale better than the pure Python list comprehension solution.  Suppose we had 6 million rows instead of 6 and needed to perform multiple element-wise operations, numpy would be better.  For example, if we have

```
data = [
  [-20],
  [-23],
  [-41],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
] * 1000000

arr = pad_array(data) #this takes ~6 seconds
```

The timings are much more in favor of numpy

```
%timeit [min(row) for row in data]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.05 s per loop

%timeit np.nanmin(arr, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop
```

Comment: Very nice answer.  Thanks for taking the time to compose that!

Comment: This answer deserves a lot more upvotes just for the thoroughness.  Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a list comprehension?

```
>>> d
[[-20], [-23], [-41], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> [max(sublist) for sublist in d]
[-20, -23, -41, 3, 3, 9]
>>> [min(sublist) for sublist in d]
[-20, -23, -41, 1, 2, 5]
```

Will also work for a numpy array:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> d
array([[-20], [-23], [-41], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=object)
>>> [max(sublist) for sublist in d]
[-20, -23, -41, 3, 3, 9]
```

Of couse, you can make the result an array.

```
>>> array([max(sublist) for sublist in d])
array([-20, -23, -41,   3,   3,   9])
```

Comment: It will all come down to the benchmarks.  I'd still like to know how to do it with numpy if that's possible.  It would help me gain a better understanding of how the library works.