# Return value of highest index in numpy 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array in numpy that includes nans.  I need to return the value with the greatest index position along the 0 axis. The answer would reduce to a 2D array.

There are a lot of questions about finding the index position of a maximum value along an axis ([How to get the index of a maximum element in a numpy array along one axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469286/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-maximum-element-in-a-numpy-array-along-one-axis)), but that is different than what I need.

Example 3D array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> foo = np.asarray([[[7,4,6],[4,2,11], [7,8,9], [4,8,2]],[[1,2,3],[np.nan,5,8], [np.nan,np.nan,10], [np.nan,np.nan,7]]])
>>> foo
array([[[  7.,   4.,   6.],
        [  4.,   2.,  11.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [  4.,   8.,   2.]],

       [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [ nan,   5.,   8.],
        [ nan,  nan,  10.],
        [ nan,  nan,   7.]]])
```

I thought I was getting close using np.where but it returns all elements that are not nan. Not quite what I need because I want a `(4,3)` array.

```
>>> zoo = foo[np.where(~np.isnan(foo))]
>>> zoo
array([  7.,   4.,   6.,   4.,   2.,  11.,   7.,   8.,   9.,   4.,   8.,
     2.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   5.,   8.,  10.,   7.])
```

The answer I need is:

```
>>> ans = np.asarray([[1,2,3], [4,5,8], [7,8,10], [4,8,7]])
>>> ans
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  8],
       [ 7,  8, 10],
       [ 4,  8,  7]])
```

EDIT: I edited the foo example array to make the question more clear.

Comment: Use `nanmax` : `np.nanmax(foo,axis=0)`?

Comment: Thanks @Divakar but that isn't quite it. See my response to Edgar below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.nanmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html):

```
>>> np.nanmax(foo, axis=0)
array([[ 7.,  4.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  5., 11.],
       [ 7.,  8., 10.],
       [ 4.,  8.,  7.]])
```

The `np.nanmax` function returns the maximum of an array or maximum along an axis, ignoring any NaNs.

## EDIT

As you rightly point out in your comment, you need the value at the maximum index and the code above doesn't return that.

Instead, you can use [`apply-along-axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy-apply-along-axis):

```
>>> def highest_index(a):
...     return a[~np.isnan(a)][-1] # return non-nan value at highest index

>>> np.apply_along_axis(highest_index, 0, foo)
array([[ 1.  2.  3.]
       [ 4.  5.  8.]
       [ 7.  8. 10.]
       [ 4.  8.  7.]])
```

Comment: Thanks Edgar, but that isn't what I need. Note the difference in your array and my ans. Your array returns the maximum value along the index (which at position 2,3 is 11) but I need the value at the maximum index (which at position 2,3 is 8).

Comment: You are right! I edited my answer to produce the right result.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Edgar!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please consider upvoting :)

Comment: I sure did... apparently I don't have enough of a reputation yet for my vote to be on public display. Thanks for helping a new user. :)

Comment: Just a note of warning, while `apply_along_axis` is convenient to use here, it isn't any faster than a more explicit iteration over the last 2 axes.

Comment: @hpaulj I wondered about iterating over the 0 axis but couldn't figure out how to do it. Are you willing to show an example answer?

Comment: I was thinking terms applied this `highest_index(foo[:,i,j])` for all `i,j`.

Answer (score 0):

A vectored solution, only with indices:

```
def last_non_nan(foo):
    i = np.isnan(foo)[::-1].argmin(0)
    j,k = np.indices(foo[0].shape)
    return foo[-i-1,j,k]
```

`i` contains the index of the first not nan number in the reversed 'line'.
so `-i-1` is its index in the direct line.

```
>>> last_non_nan(foo):
  [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
   [  4.,   5.,   8.],
   [  7.,   8.,  10.],
   [  4.,   8.,   7.]]
```

Faster than `highest_index`:

```
In [5]%timeit last_non_nan(foo)
133 µs ± 29.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(highest_index,0,foo)
667 µs ± 90 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

up to 150x (40 ms vs 6 s) faster for a (10,400,400) array with 90 % nans.

It s essentially because `last_non_nan` just fetch the last non nan value in each line, when `highest_index` compute the index and fetch all non nan values.

Comment: Thanks @B.M.  I understand what `j,k` returns (the indices row wise and column wise). And it looks like returning `i ` was the step I was really missing. Could you walk me through what the line that returns `i` is doing?

Comment: Also, I tried both your answer and @Edgar in my actual code problem (which is an array of shape `(13, 414, 394`). For some reason your answer works but Edgar's does not. I don't understand why...

Comment: Thanks so much for the extra info @BM. I upvoted your answer, it just isn't public because of my new reputation.