# How to find maximum value in whole 2D array with indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I want to find the maximum value in a 2D array and the indices of the maximum value in Python using NumPy. I used

```
np.amax(array)
```

for searching for the maximum value, but I don't know how to get its indices. I could find it by using ´for` loops, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [How to get the index of a maximum element in a NumPy array along one axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469286/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-maximum-element-in-a-numpy-array-along-one-axis). The maximum of a 2D array is not the same as the maximum along some axes.

Comment: It's a duplicate of [Get the position of the biggest item in a multi-dimensional numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584243/get-the-position-of-the-biggest-item-in-a-multi-dimensional-numpy-array) instead.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584243/get-the-position-of-the-biggest-item-in-a-numpy-array), which also elaborates how to find the max value and its (1D) index, you can use `argmax()`

```
>>> a = array([[10,50,30],[60,20,40]])
>>> maxindex = a.argmax()
>>> maxindex
3
```

You can then use `unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)` to get the indices as a tuple:

```
>>> from numpy import unravel_index
>>> unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, You can test the max value using the index returned, indices returned should look like `(array([0], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64))` when you print the indices.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[200,300,400],[100,50,300]])
indices = np.where(a == a.max())
print(a[indices]) # prints [400]

# Index for max value found two times (two locations)
a = np.array([[200,400,400],[100,50,300]])
indices = np.where(a == a.max())
print(a[indices]) # prints [400 400] because two indices for max
#Now lets print the location (Index)
for index in indices:
    print(index)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use [argmax()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the index of your maximum value.

```
a = np.array([[10,50,30],[60,20,40]])
maxindex = a.argmax()
print maxindex
```

It should return:

> 3

Then you just have to compute this value to get the line and column indices.

Best