# After finding the max value in a column, then find the row for that value?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I obtain the row number that `myMax` is in?

```
import numpy as np

myArray = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
print(myArray)
myMax = max(myArray[:,3])
print(myMax)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the index of a maximum element in a numpy array along one axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469286/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-maximum-element-in-a-numpy-array-along-one-axis)

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC lol about `snake_case` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `np.where` :

```
In [1]: np.where(myArray == myMax)
Out[1]: (array([3], dtype=int64), array([3], dtype=int64))
```

Or you can use `.argmax()`

```
In [2]: myArray[:,3].argmax()
Out[2]: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `argmax`

```
arg_max = myArray[:, 3].argmax()
myArray[arg_max,:]
```

If you don't have the column like in the case above, `argmax` returns the index of the flattened array, for example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
myArray = np.random.choice(20, 20).reshape(4, 5) # max is [1,2]
arg_max = myArray.argmax() # returns 7
rows, cols = myArray.shape
myArray[int(arg_max/cols), :]
```