# How to find max value and its index in a row of 2d list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have a 2D list. I want to find the max value and its index of each row.
Here is the list

```
q_table = [[0.16,  0.40,  0.61,  0.48,  0.20],
           [0.42,  0.79,  0.64,  0.54,  0.52],
           [0.64,  0.64,  0.24,  0.93,  0.43],
           [0.33,  0.54,  0.61,  0.43,  0.29],
           [0.25,  0.56,  0.42,  0.69,  0.62]]
```

Output:

```
0.61 2
0.79 1
0.93 3
0.61 2
0.69 3

# I'm using python 3.8
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: `np.max(q_table, axis=1)`?

Comment: Using for loops

Comment: `max`, `argmax`, then column_stack the result

Comment: @QuangHoang That gives me a list of max values. This is nice also, but I need index as well.

Comment: @Ayon134 `argmax` as cs95 suggested will do that

Comment: @cs95 i used that,
for x in range(4):
    row_max = np.argmax(q_table[x,:])
    print(row_max)
but this error came,
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the index of a maximum element in a NumPy array along one axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469286/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-maximum-element-in-a-numpy-array-along-one-axis)

Comment: @satvik I followed ur link and did this code
```
s = np.argmax(q_table)
print(s)

```
it results 13, which is fine,
but it requers me to do additional calc to find exact location in 2d list.

Is there any btr way

Comment: what type of calculation?

Comment: You can use `for loop` and `max()` function.

Comment: `s = np.argmax(q_table)
rows = len(q_table)
i = int(s / rows)
j = s % rows
print('The max value ', q_table[i][j])`
but @satvik it gives me max in the whole list, not in single row.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer this gives max value index in the whole list,
I need each row max value index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested in comments you can use max to get the max values from your list and argmax for getting the position.

```
np.argmax(q_table, axis=1) #returns list of position of max value in each list.
```

```
np.max(q_table, axis=1)  # return list of max value in each  list.
```

you can then use zip function to iterate both the list together and store the  output in list of list

```
import numpy as np
max_list_with_position=[ [x,y] for x,y in zip(np.argmax(q_table, axis=1),np.max(q_table, axis=1))]
print(max_list_with_position)
```

output:

```
[[2, 0.61], [1, 0.79], [3, 0.93], [2, 0.61], [3, 0.69]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q_table = [[0.16,  0.40,  0.61,  0.48,  0.20],
           [0.42,  0.79,  0.64,  0.54,  0.52],
           [0.64,  0.64,  0.24,  0.93,  0.43],
           [0.33,  0.54,  0.61,  0.43,  0.29],
           [0.25,  0.56,  0.42,  0.69,  0.62]]

rows_count = len(q_table) # to count number of rows
for i in range(rows_count):
    a_row = q_table[i] # taking each row in a variable
    max_value = max(a_row) # find mad value in a single row
    index = a_row.index(max_value) # find the max value's index of a single row
    print("The max value ",max_value, " and Index in ",index)
```

If there is a better way do suggest.

and here is the output,

```
The max value  0.61  and Index in  2
The max value  0.79  and Index in  1
The max value  0.93  and Index in  3
The max value  0.61  and Index in  2
The max value  0.69  and Index in  3
```